# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) $ tends to infinity does it imply that $f(x)$ is eventually monotonically increasing

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=\infty  $ exists does it imply that $f(x)$ is eventually monotonically increasing.How to prove if true ?

I want to apply this on polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $x + 10 \sin(x)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, now i realized i written the question wrong

Comment: I changed it to accomodate your changes, @Milan

Answer (score 3):

The general statement, as given, is not true but it **is** true for polynomials!  If p is a polynomial of degree n, then p' is a polynomial of degree n-1.  p' has a finite number, at most n-1, of real zeros so has a largest zero.  If z is larger than that, p' does not change sign so p is monotone increasing or decreasing. (However, for polynomials, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ **never** exists.)

Comment: "never"  is a little too strong... (Also note the question was about when the limit is infinite; a polynomial "always" has a limit in $[-\infty,\infty]$.)